# Write point forecast value in R

Tags: r, forecasting

```
data_test <- NULL
for(i in 1:ncol(dataset)) {
  col <- ts(dataset[,i])
  fit1 <- auto.arima(col, trace=TRUE))
  fcast <- forecast(fit1,h=12, level=c(90,95))
  data_test <- cbind(data_test, fcast$lower)
}

write.table(data_test, "Forecast.csv", sep=";", dec=",", append=TRUE)
```

I would like to write the Point forecast instead of the `fcast@lower`, though when I type `names(fcast)` in my R-script, I get:

`[1] "method"    "model"     "level"     "mean"      "lower"     "upper"     "x"         "xname"     "fitted"    "residuals"`

my question: where is the point forecast? and how do I write out the point forecast (and only the point forecast)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page, `?forecast`, is very straightforward:

> `mean` Point forecasts as a time series